# Yii2 PHP get first day in week and last day of month from date

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have 3 fields name `"date_submit"`, `"week_submit"`, `"month_submit"`.

How can I get week and month from the date field automatically in PHP. Example:

If `"date_submit" = 2017-12-16` then `"week_submit" = 2017-12-11` and `"month_submit" = 2017-12-31`

I'm using Yii2 basic template.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try like  `"date_submit", SUBDATE(date_submit, WEEKDAY(date_submit)) as week_submit, LAST_DAY(date_submit) as month_submit`. It should work for you.

Comment: Can you show me example? thank you :)

Comment: You mean in SQL or PHP  ???  show a clear code sample

Comment: Yes, its into SQL like `SELECT date_submit, SUBDATE(date_submit, WEEKDAY(date_submit)) as week_submit, LAST_DAY(date_submit) as month_submit FROM <tablename>'`

Comment: @scaisEdge I mean in php, in Yii2. Sorry for not being clear from the beginning. For the code I still figuring this out so I don't have code yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have $date_submit value and you want to get new desired values in $week_submit and $month_submit. Try this:

```
$date='2017-12-18';//$_POST['date_submit'];//date('Y-m-d');//'2017-12-19';
$day = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
$day->setISODate((int)$day->format('o'), (int)$day->format('W'), 1);
$week_submit = $day->format('Y-m-d');

$month_submit=date("Y-m-t", strtotime($date));

print_r ('Week submit: '.$week_submit.'<br>'.'Month submit: '.$month_submit);
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) this is perfect

Comment: It's my pleasure :)